# How to get the Exception information from Marshal.GetExceptionCode();

Tags: .net, exception

When using Marshal.GetExceptionCode() how do you get the Exception Type and/or instance of the exception?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptioncode%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works.  Marshal.GetExceptionCode only returns a meaningful number if the CLR has caught an SEH exception.  It will try to translate the exception into a meaningful managed exception.  The common ones are NullReferenceException, OverflowException, DivideByZeroException, StackOverflowException, AccessViolationException.  SEHException is the fall-back one.

You can call GetExceptionCode while handling one of those exceptions.  Chicken-and-egg, the managed exception gets raised first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want [GetExceptionForHR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t3ykxc.aspx), but it is only available for .NET 2.0 and above.